# Clicking a Button in a button array

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the code below.

```
public void WepaonEquip(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (button[0].BackColor == Color.Beige)
{
    button[0].BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
}

else if (button[1].BackColor == Color.Beige)
{
    button[1].BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
}

else if (button[2].BackColor == Color.Beige)
{
    button[2].BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
}
}
```

The code in the class containing this chunk of code generates a button array. What I want is that the user will click a button and the colour of the button clicked will change.

However, when the user clicks, lets say, the 3rd button, the **first** button in the array changes colour, not the one clicked. Any idea as to why this isn't working? I believe the logic of the code works, perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set each button in the panel to use the same Click Event handler.  In the handler cast sender as a button and change the color

Assuming that WeaponEquip is the click event handler for the buttons it would look something like this:

```
public void WepaonEquip(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedbutton = (Button)sender
    clickedbutton.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;

}
```

Comment: sorry, panel1 is irrelevent, ill take that off

Comment: That's fine, the concept will still work with whichever buttons you want to handle.

Comment: alright, i added them into one click event, but nothing changed, see above for edited code

Comment: @user3170251 You do not need to use conditional logic to test for every button, the sender is the button that was clicked, just do what tinstaafl said and cast it to a button then test your color.